# C: Creating an array of structs in a for loop

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to create an array made from structs (or maybe creating the struct array?) in a loop, the code works for single struct, but I need to create 5 of them in a loop usig losuj_liczbe function, to asign random number. Each time I get this error: 
variable-sized object may not be initialized.
Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define n 5

typedef enum
{
    Bialy,
    Czarny,
    Czerwony,
    Niebieski
}Kolor;

typedef enum
{
    Podstawowe,
    Standard,
    Premium
}Wyposazenie;

typedef struct Samochod
{
    int waga;
    int cena;
    Kolor kolor;
    Wyposazenie wyposazenie;
}Samochod;

int losuj_liczbe(int min, int max)
{
    int rolex;
    time_t tt;
    rolex=time(tt);
    srand(rolex);

    int temp;
    if (max >=min)
        max -= min;
    else{
        temp = min - max;
        min = max;
        max = temp;
    }
    return ((rand()% (max-min) + min));
}


int main()
{
    int i;
    Samochod automobil[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    Samochod automobil[i] = {{.waga = losuj_liczbe(500,1500),
                .cena = losuj_liczbe(20000,30000),
                .kolor = ((0 == losuj_liczbe(0,3)) ? Bialy :(1 == losuj_liczbe(0,3)) ? Czarny :(2 == losuj_liczbe(0,3)) ? Czerwony : Niebieski),
                .wyposazenie = ((0 == losuj_liczbe(0,2)) ? Podstawowe :(1 == losuj_liczbe(0,2)) ? Standard : Premium)}};
    }
    printf("%d | %d | %s | %s",
           automobil.waga,
           automobil.cena,
           (0 == automobil.kolor) ? "Bialy" : (1 == automobil.kolor) ? "Czarny" : (2 == automobil.kolor) ? "Czerwony" : "Niebieski",
           (0 == automobil.wyposazenie) ? "Podstawowe" : (1 == automobil.wyposazenie) ? "Standard" : "Premium");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error? What is your platform and compiler version?

Comment: It's highly recommended to write your code in english. Sooner or later, you'll show it to people speaking a different language than you (like you do here!) and understanding the semantics of the code helps a lot with spotting errors.

Comment: There are many issues. What output do you expect? Answers depend on the expected output.

Comment: Also what values are you expecting to print , shouldn't you specify the struct number in the printf?

Comment: Side note: the way you resolve the car color is absolutely unreadable: `(0 == automobil.kolor) ? "Bialy" : (1 == automobil.kolor) ? "Czarny" : (2 == automobil.kolor) ? "Czerwony" : "Niebieski"`.

Comment: the error shows up in line 54:
error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

sorry for the language of my code, but I'm trying to figure out what to do with this error...

Comment: (0 == automobil.kolor) ? "Bialy" : (1 == automobil.kolor) ? "Czarny" : (2 == automobil.kolor) ? "Czerwony" : "Niebieski"

This is the only way known to me, that works...

Comment: You should make a function that returns a pointer to the color string: e.g. `const char *GetColorName(Kolor colorname)`. And in your printf statement you'd write `..., automobil.cena, GetColorName(automobil.kolor), ...`. But this is just a side  note unrelated to your problem.

Comment: `rolex=time(tt);` -->> `rolex=time(&tt);` ... or even better: `tt = time(NULL);`

Comment: `#define n 5` = pure evil.

Comment: `Samochod automobil[i]` tries to create a *new array* of size `i`, not access the array already defined. Just remove the type name.

Comment: After deleting the type name now tells me this error in the line 58:
expected expression before '{' token|

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues:

Just to name a few:

- `srand` should be called only once at the start of the programm. And a single `srand(time(NULL));` is enough. Read the documentation of the `srand` and `time` functions
- the assignments of `automobil[i]` in the first loop are all wrong
- your `printf` is wrong and pointless, you need to do another `for` loop to display all cars.
- you need to put a `\n` at the end of the `printf` format string.
- by convention all macro names should be in capitals, so instead of `#define n 5` you should have `#define NUMBEROFCARS 5`. And you should absolutely avoid short macro names such as `N`, `A`, `X`. This is just a matter of readability.

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUMBEROFCARS 5

typedef enum
{
  Bialy,
  Czarny,
  Czerwony,
  Niebieski
}Kolor;

typedef enum
{
  Podstawowe,
  Standard,
  Premium
}Wyposazenie;

typedef struct Samochod
{
  int waga;
  int cena;
  Kolor kolor;
  Wyposazenie wyposazenie;
}Samochod;

int losuj_liczbe(int min, int max)
{
  int temp;
  if (max >= min)
    max -= min;
  else {
    temp = min - max;
    min = max;
    max = temp;
  }
  return ((rand() % (max - min) + min));
}


int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));

  int i;
  Samochod automobil[NUMBEROFCARS];

  for (i = 0; i < NUMBEROFCARS; i++) {
    automobil[i].waga = losuj_liczbe(500, 1500);
    automobil[i].cena = losuj_liczbe(20000, 30000);
    automobil[i].kolor = ((0 == losuj_liczbe(0, 3)) ? Bialy : (1 == losuj_liczbe(0, 3)) ? Czarny : (2 == losuj_liczbe(0, 3)) ? Czerwony : Niebieski);
    automobil[i].wyposazenie = ((0 == losuj_liczbe(0,2)) ? Podstawowe : (1 == losuj_liczbe(0,2)) ? Standard : Premium);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < NUMBEROFCARS; i++) {
    printf("%d | %d | %s | %s\n",
      automobil[i].waga,
      automobil[i].cena,
      (0 == automobil[i].kolor) ? "Bialy" : (1 == automobil[i].kolor) ? "Czarny" : (2 == automobil[i].kolor) ? "Czerwony" : "Niebieski",
      (0 == automobil[i].wyposazenie) ? "Podstawowe" : (1 == automobil[i].wyposazenie) ? "Standard" : "Premium");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This program is still awkward, especially the horrible ternary expressions for converting the color to the color name should be refactored.

Answer (score 0):

Look at in-line comments of correct code version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* Use readable names */
#define NUM_OF_AUTOMOBIL 5

typedef enum {
    Bialy = 0,
    Czarny,
    Czerwony,
    Niebieski,
} Kolor;

/* Use predefined array of string.
 * Look at printf() to see how to use it to simplify your code
 */
const char *KolorStr[] = {
    "Bialy",
    "Czarny",
    "Czerwony",
    "Niebieski"
};

typedef enum {
    Podstawowe = 0,
    Standard,
    Premium
} Wyposazenie;

const char *WyposazenieStr[] = {
    "Podstawowe",
    "Standard",
    "Premium"
};

typedef struct Samochod {
    int waga;
    int cena;
    Kolor kolor;
    Wyposazenie wyposazenie;
} Samochod;

int losuj_liczbe(int min, int max)
{
    assert(max != min);

    if (max < min) {
        int temp = min - max;
        min = max;
        max = temp;
    }

    /* Use parenthes even if you completely sure of precedence, this allows
     * to avoid mistakes during code modification
     */
    return ((rand() % (max - min)) + min);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Samochod automobil[NUM_OF_AUTOMOBIL];

    /* Init random generator once over all your program
     */
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_AUTOMOBIL; i++) {
        automobil[i].waga = losuj_liczbe(500, 1500);
        automobil[i].cena = losuj_liczbe(20000, 30000);
        /* You can convert int into enum directly if
         * limit int with enum values only */
        automobil[i].kolor = losuj_liczbe(Bialy, Niebieski);
        automobil[i].wyposazenie = losuj_liczbe(Podstawowe, Premium);
    }

    /* Use loop over your array to show values
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_AUTOMOBIL; i++) {
        /* Use \n to terminate your lines
         */
        printf("%d | %d | %s | %s\n",
                automobil[i].waga,
                automobil[i].cena,
                KolorStr[automobil[i].kolor],
                WyposazenieStr[automobil[i].wyposazenie]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```